# Why does setting a python 2.7 list cross class boundaries

Tags: python, list, class, python-2.7

In the following code, why does setting the email_attachments list to 'attach1' in class test1 also set the email_attachments list in class test2 to 'attach1'?

Class:

```
class classtest:
    smtp_server = ""
    smtp_port = 0
    email_attachments = []

    def class_print(self):

        print self.smtp_server
        print self.smtp_port
        print self.email_attachments
```

Script:

```
import ClassTest

def main():
    test1 = ClassTest.classtest()
    test1.smtp_server = "server1"
    test1.smtp_port = "1"
    test1.email_attachments.append("attach1")
    test1.class_print()

    print

    test2 = ClassTest.classtest()
    test2.smtp_server = "server2"
    test2.class_print()

main()
```

results:

server1

1

['attach1']

server2

0

['attach1']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3 variables you have defined at the top of the class are associated with the class itself, not with a particular instance of the class, so their values are shared between test1 and test2.

If your intention is to have separate values for each object of type `classtest` then you should define a constructor and use the 'self' prefix with each variable:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.smtp_server = ""
    self.smtp_port = 0
    self.email_attachments = []
```